# How to use "%" char in Worklight SQL adapter?

Tags: sql, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I want use "%" char in Worklight SQL Adapter.

It's my Code:

```
var selectStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("SELECT * FROM studentinfo WHERE studentinfo.sname like '%?%'");
function getStudentInfos(param1) {   

    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : selectStatement,
        parameters : [param1]
    });
}
```

But It's error:

```
{
   "errors": [
      "Runtime: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0)..\nPerformed query:\nSELECT * FROM studentinfo WHERE studentinfo.sname like '%?%'"
   ],
   "info": [
   ],
   "isSuccessful": false,
   "warnings": [
   ]
}
```

How should I use "%" Char in Worklight SQL Adapter?

Comment: Do you want to search "?"  ?

Comment: No,"?" is a param1.refer to (http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/04_03_SQL_adapter_-_Communicating_with_SQL_database.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
var selectStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("SELECT * FROM studentinfo WHERE studentinfo.sname like ?");
function getStudentInfos(param1) {   

    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : selectStatement,
        parameters : [new String("%" + param1 + "%")]
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is**

```
("SELECT * FROM studentinfo WHERE studentinfo.sname like '%?%'");
```

The "%" sign is used to define wildcards (missing letters) both before and after the pattern. after "%"  sign mention your desire word which you want to search.